# String to Array JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in my JQuery file:

```
$("#getFile").click(function() {
  var fileName = $("#loadpFile").val()

  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "readFile.py", 
    data: {name:fileName}
  })

  .done(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  })

  .fail(function() {
    alert('Malformed response from server');
  })
});
```

When #getFile is pressed, the #loadpFile gives the name of the data file that must be referenced. This data file returns this:

```
"['#10.4_16', '#10.4_17', '#10.4_18']"
```

How can I access this as an array?

When I do this:

```
.done(function(data) {
    console.log($.parseJSON(data))
  })
```

I get this: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

What can I do?

Comment: Why do you get it as a string at first place? How do you generate it? (it's not a valid JSON obviously)

Comment: That string is not valid JSON. Strings in valid JSON should be wrapped in double quotes. [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.org) is a useful site to test the validity of json.

Comment: The string should be: '["#10.4_16", "..", "..."]', notice the quotes...

Comment: I thought JSON might solve this, but I didn't know enough about it to tell. I will remove the JSON flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'` (single quote) isn't a valid delimiter in a JSON string.  You'll need to replace it in order to parse it:

```
JSON.parse("['#10.4_16', '#10.4_17', '#10.4_18']".replace(/'/g, '"'));
```

However, this is a temporary fix.  I'd suggest going to wherever's generating that string and ensuring it outputs proper JSON in the first place.

Comment: My current header is :print "Content-Type: text/html", but when I use print "Content-Type: application/json", it fails and I couldn't figure out why. Since html worked, I just went with it.

Comment: It's probably failing on `application/json` because the service is returning invalid JSON.

Comment: I'm using python, and I just sent my data like this: print json.dump(array). It was read correctly without the eval now. Thank you. ;)

Answer (score -2):

For your return example, you can try this:

```
data = data.replace("[","{").replace("]", "}");
eval("data = " + data+";");
```

Comment: If you know what you will have as return you can do it very well. There is no return to avoid that pratice. But if is possible that you receive dangerous code as return I agree with you.

Comment: Thank you! I am using eval, but I will always be receiving an array like that from the file so it should be fine.

Comment: Why are you changing it to an object (which is invalid syntax now) instead of keeping the array?

Comment: You are welcome. If you don´t matter in vote in my answer it will be great ;).

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I have to parse through the array and use those as selectors, so I need it to be an object. I'm using this: data = eval(data).